# php placement of the dot in a long number

Tags: php

I want to display a large number with a leading zero and a dot after.

The balance i want to display starts with 0.000000000000000000 ( 18 zeros after the dot ). This should be able to go up to 99.00000000000000000.( 17 zeros after the dot ).

I did a lot of trial and error but i just can't seem to get the dot in there. As far as for the zeros i got it working. What i have now is:

```
$leadingBalance = sprintf("%019d", $balance);
echo $leadingBalance;
```

This will display the correct balance but i need to place the dot in there. It means that if my balance has 17 or 18 numbers it should place the dot as 0.0000... If the balance has 19 numbers it should place the dot as 00.0000...

Whatever i try, how much i look up i can't figure it out.

Comment: "%020d" thats it

Comment: The zero's aren't the issue. The dot is. I can get the right amount of zero's but now i need the dot at the right location.

Comment: if the $leadingbalance is 15 how many zero u want after dot?

Answer (score 1):

For eg:

```
$n1 = 0;
$n2 = 99;
 echo number_format($n1,18)."<br>"; 
 echo number_format($n2,18)."<br>";
```

See the documentation for number_format: http://php.net/number_format

The functions parameters are:

```
string number_format ( float $number , int $decimals = 0 , string $dec_point = '.' , string $thousands_sep = ',' )
```

So use:

```
number_format(1000000000000000, 2, '.', '');
```

Which means that you don't use any (= empty string) thousands separator, only a decimal point.

or if **you just want padding of 19 zero after decimal point**

just use

```
 sprintf("%0.19f",$number);
```

or else

if u want a number always 20 digit without caring about whole no and decimal value than use  **str_pad()**

eg:

```
$no = sprintf("%0.2f",100); //100.00
```

this will convert your no to decimal point with 2 digit after decimal now just pad some digit if require to make it 20 digit long

```
  echo str_pad($no,20,"0"); //100.00(15 zero after this)
```

this will check no of digit available and pad 0 to make it 20 digit

for more ref:https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_number_format.asp

Comment: Trust me i tried. This will result in a number like "17,211,443,063,862,076.000000000000000000". I only need one dot at the right location.

Comment: its just one step forward on the road... i have edited my code... so please check it now and let me know

Comment: Even though the dot will be placed at the end of the number with zero's following.

Comment: try with sprintf("%0.19f",$number);

Comment: if u want a number always 20 digit without caring about whole no and decimal value than use     str_pad()                                                                       eg:$no =  sprintf("%0.2f",100);
echo str_pad($no,20,"0");

Answer (score 0):

You are using `%019d` when you actually wants a float number, try this:

```
<?php
    $format = '%0.19f';
    $args = 9;
    $result = sprintf ($format, $args);
    //$result will be equal to 9.0000000000000000000
?>
```

---

```
<?php
    $format = '%0.19f';
    $args = 99;
    $result = sprintf ($format, $args);
    //$result will be equal to 99.0000000000000000000
?>
```

### Edit:

Since it looks like you want your whole number to be equal to 20 digits only, you may try to do some math if `number_format` doesn't do your job. You can try something like:

```
<?php
    $number = 999;
    $number_length = strlen($number);
    $format_len = 20 - $number_length;
    $format = '%0.'. $format_len .'f';
    $result = sprintf($format, $number);
?>
```

Comment: This will also result in: 17211443063862076.0000000000000000000 using 17211443063862077 as balance.

Comment: So you actually want your whole number to be equal to 20 characters?

Comment: When a balance is 0.01 the number is 17 digits long. When the balance is 0.1 the number is 18 digits long and when its 1.0 its 19 digits long.

Comment: So if I correctly understood what you're saying, you want your whole number to be equal to 20 digits, 0.01 = 0.0100000000000000000, and 100 = 100.00000000000000000 ?

Comment: @user3299251 updated my answer as I felt you needed it.

Comment: Somehow correct. The thing is that i get data with specific lengths which will define the amount it's worth. 17 digits means 0.01, 18 digits means 0.1, 19 digits means 1.0, 20 digits means 10.0 and 21 digits means 100.0 etc. So the initial number can be different lengths ( 17 till unlimited ( in theory )

Comment: @user3299251 I am having a bit of trouble to understand now, could you please update your question adding at least 5 different inputs you have and their outcomes? Having a small number and a big number..